# Unable to test login functionality, with single credentials with 2 threads using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am a new user of Jmeter and trying to understand the issue I am facing. I am testing login functionality of a website using single credential and 2 threads.
When test is executed, test results for:

```
Thread 1 shows - Pass 
Thread 2 shows - Fail
```

The reason of failure for Thread 2, when I see in Response Body says:

```
errors: {code:"sameip", message:"user is currently logged in. Please wait for this user's session to timeout. Or you may force to login by entering your username and password."}`
```

The failure reason is valid as my thread 1 has logged in, my thread 2 cannot login as the session is live.

How to resolve this scenario? Or Is there another way to this scenario?

I came across **CSV config** but it needs list of different user id's and password in it. But, my scenario is using only one user id and password.

Answer (score 0):

```
errors: {code:"sameip"
               ^^^^^^
```

It looks like your application is checking [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) of the logged in user and prevents multiple concurrent logins from the same IP.

If this is the case you can use different IP addresses (or [IP aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)) for your 2 threads so each thread would use its own source IP address.

The setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

More information: [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter)